# Find a, b, c from second degree polynomial interpolation formula

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods, interpolation

Linear interpolation formula $$ g(x)=f_j+\frac{x-x_j}{x_{j+1}-x_j}(f_{j+1}-f_i) $$ where answer is $ y=ax+b $ can be changed to $$ a=\frac{f_{j+1}-f_j}{x_{j+1}-x_j} \\b=f_j-x_j\frac{f_{j+1}-f_j}{x_{j+1}-x_j} $$ so it can be programmed in C language, where you can't calculate with few unknown variables.

Can someone help me transform/find already transformed second degree polynomial interpolation formula $$ g(x) = f_j \frac{(x-x_{j+1})(x-x_{j+2})}{(x_j-x_{j+1})(x_j-x_{j+2})}+ \\+f_{j+1} \frac{(x-x_j)(x-x_{j+2})}{(x_{j+1}-x_j)(x_{j+1}-x_{j+2})}+ \\f_{j+2} \frac{(x-x_j)(x-x_{j+1})}{(x_{j+2}-x_j)(x_{j+2}-x_{j+1})} $$ where answer is $ y=ax^2+bx+c $ like in linear interpolation example where it would be solvable for $a, b$ and $c$ having data table and not knowing $ x $ .

Comment: So you specifically need the coefficients of $1,x,x^2$, other bases aren't OK? This can be done with linear algebra once you know how to write the basis you're actually dealing with (in this case the Lagrange basis) in terms of the monomial basis. With that said, this is an *extremely* standard problem with a vast array of libraries available that can handle it, so if you're having trouble I might suggest just using one of those.

Comment: @Ian I need to write a program what uses array of  $x_i, f_i$ data points and interpolates by lines and second degree polynomials. Linear interpolation part was easy, but I'm stuck on 2nd degree polynomial part, because I need those coefficients, so I can format my output properly. (f.e.:  Answer is $ 4x^2+3x-1 $).

Comment: And you need to write your own?

Comment: If you do, there's a simple enough way to do it: you need to work out the coefficients of each of the basis elements in the monomial basis. Specifically, you want the coefficient of $x^i$ in $p_j(x)$ to be $a_{ij}$. Then you can multiply out $Af$, where $f$ is your vector of coefficients in the Lagrange basis, to get the coefficients in the monomial basis. Note that depending on the nodes this may introduce large numerical errors that weren't present before.

Comment: Alternatively, you can proceed directly, solving the system in the monomial basis in the first place. After all, what you really want to solve is $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & x_1 & x_1^2 \\ 1 & x_2 & x_2^2 \\ 1 & x_3 & x_3^2 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} c \\ b \\ a \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} f_1 \\ f_2 \\ f_3 \end{bmatrix}$ which is already a linear system. This may lead to even *larger* numerical errors than the Lagrange approach, however.

Comment: @Ian Thanks for the help! The linear system method, since it seems to be easiest to program. Thank you for you time and help!